# How To Create UICustomeViewCell

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I Am New to iphone Programing,can any one help me out how to create a UICustomviewCell with image view and textlabel That should change dynamically...

Comment: Have you already checked/searched for any docs yourself?

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4931120/iphone-uitableviewcell-customcell

Answer (score 1):

Download [TableViewSuite](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TableViewSuite/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple developer site. There you learn about how to create custom table cell.